# QGIS Points to Path Plugin Date/time error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, csv, spatio-temporal-data

I would like to use the Points to Paths plugin to plot the tracks of collared animals, exactly as specified on this page http://spatialgalaxy.net/2011/12/30/qgis-plugin-of-the-week-points-to-paths/

However, my date/time is in this format '2013/06/06 00:25' and the plugin reports this error:

ValueError: Order field is not an integer type or date format is invalid

I can get the plugin to work using time in HH:MM:SS only (so it's not my order field at fault) but as the animals are tracked over several days this is not practical. I cannot find in any of my three spreadsheet programs a date/time format option that uses '-' as the date separator as shown in the box? Does the plugin support my date/time format, and if so, what syntax should I use in the plugin's date format box? 
Or can anyone tell me how to generate a CSV file with date/time in the 2013-06-25T00:25 format that the plugin shows?
Thanks!
PS Am generating the date/time field by adding together separate date and time columns in the raw data

Comment: Is your input format YYYY/MM/DD or YYYY/DD/MM? How are you currently generating the datetime field? In Excel? In a script?

Comment: @underdark The data comes in an Excel file as two columns, YYYY/MM/DD and time in 24hr clock hours:min:sec. I then insert a column in Excel and put in =A1+B1 to get date/time. There is only one custom format available for this, which the plugin does not seem to like. I then export to CSV from Excel, but have also tried Calc for more formats. I do not know how to do scripts, or how to write the equivalent of %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M. I tried a few logical variations of this but I think the / separator is maybe the problem?

Comment: Update - I found out how to change my date settings in Excel so my date now looks like 2013-06-06 00:25:23, but I still cannot get the plugin to recognise this. I think in my CSV it is recorded as text? How do I get around this?

Comment: Sadly I don't know how to remove this question now that I have solved my own problem. I have figured out the formatting :-) and Points to Paths is working, only sadly if the collar misses sending data at one time slot the path breaks and resumes at a later time slot. To get Excel to display the correct date setting I had to change the formatting options in the 'custom' format field, I did not realise this was possible, so this is not actually a QGIS plugin problem